# Jquery run function on success

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, datatables

I have ajax code and function `drawVisualisation();`

When I load page I have code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    drawVisualization();
});
```

and code work well, but when I call ajax on success function I also call function:

```
success: function(data) {
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    drawVisualization();
    console.log('SUCCESS'); 
    $('#addFieldForm').each (function(){
        this.reset();
    });
```

but this time the function was called but my `#example` div dont want to refresh

How to refresh the `#example` when I call second time function `drawVisualisation();`?

Function:

```
function drawVisualization() {
   $('#example').dataTable({
       "ajax": "getN.php",
       paging: false,
       //"dom":' <"search"f><"top"l>rt<"bottom"ip><"clear">',
       "fnFooterCallback": function (nRow, aasData, iStart, iEnd, aiDisplay) {
           var columnas = [2, 3, 4]; //the columns you wish to add            
           for (var j in columnas) {
               var columnaActual = columnas[j];
               var total = 0;
               for (var i = iStart; i < iEnd; i++) {
                   total = total + parseFloat(aasData[aiDisplay[i]][columnaActual]);
               }
               $($(nRow).children().get(columnaActual-1)).html(total);
           }
       }, // end ,
       "columns": 
       [
           {"data": "ID"},
           {"data": "naziv"},
           {"data": "ha"},
           {"data": "ar"},
           {"data": "m2"},
           {"data": "lokacija"},
           {"data": "osnov"},
           {"data": "kat_kul"},
           {"data": "akcija"}
       ],
       "columnDefs": 
       [
           {
               "targets": 8,
               "data": "akcija",
               "render": function(data, type, full, meta) {
                   // return data; 
                   return '<div style="float:right;"><button class="btn btn-warning">Izmeni</button> <button class="btn btn-info">Izvestaj o parceli</button> <i class="fa fa-times"></i></div>';
               }
           },
           {"targets": 0, "visible":false}
       ]
   });
};
```

Comment: I see in your code this : `$('#addFieldForm').each (function(){` , and this makes me wonder how many elements with `id="addFieldForm"` you actualy have. More than one?

Comment: this is not a problem, ajax work fine, but I call drawVisualisation to refresh div #example with new data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `destroy` datable on your element first, then you can init datables for that element again:

```
success: function(data) {
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    // destroy old:
    $('#example').dataTable().fnDestroy();
    drawVisualization();
    console.log('SUCCESS'); 
    $('#addFieldForm').reset();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this to force your element to refresh. I've used it sometimes and it works as longs as you have the problem with webkit but I guess it should work for other browsers as well if you just remove "-webkit-"

```
element.style.webkitTransform = 'scale(1)';
```

Comment: I use datatable so maybe that is the problem? Everything work fine on document ready, but when I try to call witout doc ready then is a problem

Comment: WHEN I CALL DRAWVISUALISATION BY CONSOLE.LOG THEN i GET MESSAGE : UNDEFINED

Comment: Try to debug your javascript in your browser to see where you get undefined. If you declared the function in $(document).ready() you cannot call it from outside that function.